# assigning the id in html through the javascript DOM concept

Tags: javascript, html

```
<body>
<input type="button" value="ADD" onClick="add()">
<table id="myTable">

</table>
<table id="myTable2">

</table>
<table id="myTable3">

</table>
</body>
```

In the above Code I am creating one table dynamically from the programming part, based on the result which I get.

My question, How can i give the id part in the table dynamically?

ie  table id="myTable3" ---> table3 is given for the 3rd row element

2)  table2 is given for the 2nd row element

Since we cant have same id in the same HTML so i am creating sequentially and assigning as id

Can any one suggest with some sample javascript code about assigning the id dynamically.
So that I can have a better control later

Comment: provide your code that creates tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to this you only need one simple DOM traversal function. [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName).

You can then create an all purpose function that loops through your elements and adds the id.

```
function addIds(container, elName, prefix){
    // get the container
    var container=document.getElementById(container);
    // get tables
    var tables=container.getElementsByTagName(elName);
    // loop through tables
    for(var i=0;i<tables.length;i++)
        // add ids
        tables[i].id=prefix+(i+1);
}
```

Since I doubt you want to affect ALL elements in your page, I have created this function that takes a container and then looks inside it for elements with your specified tag and then adds ids to them with a prefix.

### Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Khez/5GuVw/) of it in action on jsfiddle.

Comment: with this sample we should be able to create a table with the unique id, is that possible to give the unique id for the every td inside this table??

Comment: @harigm, exact same function, used in the exact same way.

Answer (score 2):

```
var  table=document.createElement("table"); 
table.setAttribute("id", "table3");
parent.appendChild(table);
```

where `parent` is the container element of the table.You can declare a global counter and use its value to assign the id every time you dynamically create a table

Comment: with this sample we should be able to create a table with the unique id, is that possible to give the unique id for the every td inside this table??

Comment: yes of course.You can use the value of the global counter i mentioned and append string or number to that value to assign id's inside this table

Answer (score 0):

```
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');

for (var i =0; i < tables.length; i++){
  tables[i].id = "table"+i;
}
```

now your table id will be serialized

Comment: with this sample we should be able to create a table with the unique id, is that possible to give the unique id for the every td inside this table??

Comment: yes you can follow the same procedure. get the `td` the same way using `var tds = table[i].getElementsByTagName('td');` now you can also loop through these and assign them an id.